# torchvision's FCOS Implementation question

Tags: pytorch, object-detection, torch, torchvision

In the [code](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/torchvision/models/detection/fcos.py) of FCOS implemented in torchvision, we can clearly see that anchors are used. For example on line 396 anchor_generator is defined if there is no anchor_generator defined while instantiating the class. However in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.01355.pdf) we read that the model is completely anchor-free. Could someone explain the reason why anchors are used?

Comment: perhaps ask that on their github, in an issue.

Comment: Ahh yes that's a good idea, not sure why I didn't think about that. Thank you